# Google Cloud and Go creating instances

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

thanks for looking at my post. i need to create an Linux instance with go lang and display the created public IP on the webpage.

Comment: I would suggest look at the GCE documentation.

Comment: i checked the GCE documentation and its of no help

Comment: Can you suggest any code please

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 4):

Actually this is well hidden in the API docs.
First you need to get an Google Cloud SDK Client authenticated.
Then you might want to look at the following API operations:

- https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1#InstancesService.Insert
- https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1#Operation
- https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1#InstancesService.List

Comment: Wow, thank you! I have spent literal hours looking for these endpoints. I thought that maybe they did not exist publicly and were only available via `gcloud`. Any chance you might know of any good documentation that maps `gcloud` commands to API endpoints? Or where the `gcloud` source may be available?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/making-requests.html and then calling `DescribeInstances` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html), should give you the public IP address.

Some pointers which *may* help here (haven't used these): https://gist.github.com/stephen-mw/9f289d724c4cfd3c88f2 and http://www.heystephenwood.com/search/label/aws

Hope this helps.

Comment: These are great links if this question had been about **AWS/EC2**, but it's about **GCP**...